# Isotope filtering by beginning of the class of the element

Tags: jquery, wordpress, filtering, categories, jquery-isotope

I am using the Isotope filter by category for the Wordpress posts. Often the posts are the children of the filtered categories so their classes contain the parent's category name in the name of the class but not equal to this name. For example, the filters are Facebook, Twitter, Youtube. And the class name is facebook-pages or twitter-infographics. So these posts are not being filtered, unless the parent category is checked as well. The code I use now is the following (the jQuery non-conflict mode):

```
var $jcontainer = $j('#portfolio-list');
$jcontainer.imagesLoaded( function() {
// initialize isotope
$jcontainer.isotope({
  filter: '*',
  itemSelector : '.post',
  layoutMode : 'masonry',
});
});

$j('#portfolio-filter a').click(function(){
    $j('#portfolio-filter .current').removeClass('current');
    $j(this).addClass('current');

    var selector = $j(this).attr('data-filter');
    $jcontainer.isotope({
        filter: selector,
     });
     return false;
});
```

I would like to know how to get it work by the part of the text of the class. Thank you for any help.

## Solution

After some research I found the solution. I realized that I can use **.match** function to check the class before filtering, and then to assign a class ".match" to each matched element. Then just to filter by this class!) Here is the code. Hope it will help to somebody!

```
// cache container
var $jcontainer = $j('#portfolio-list');
$jcontainer.imagesLoaded( function() {
// initialize isotope
$jcontainer.isotope({
  filter: '*',
  itemSelector : '.post',
  layoutMode : 'masonry',
});
});

$j('#portfolio-filter a').click(function(){
    $j('#portfolio-filter .current').removeClass('current');
    $j('#portfolio-list .match').removeClass('match');
    $j(this).addClass('current');
    var selector = $j(this).attr('data-filter');
    $j('#portfolio-list article' ).each(function() {
       if ($j(this).attr('class').match(new RegExp(selector))) {
        $j(this).addClass('match');
    }
    }); 

    $jcontainer.isotope({
        filter: '.match',
     });
     return false;
});
```

Comment: As you can read in the isotope docs, it uses a jQuery selector for filtering – so go look at those to find one that allows you to select an element only by the _beginning_ part if its class. (If you targeted elements contain only _one_ class name, then the Attribute Contains Prefix Selector might work.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment CBroe, it gave me a good direction :) I've edited the post to show the solution

Comment: You should make that an answer (self-answer) instead … chance to get additional reputation ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

After some research I found the solution. I realized that I can use .match function to check the class before filtering, and then to assign a class ".match" to each matched element. Then just to filter by this class!) Here is the code. Hope it will help to somebody!

```html
// cache container
var $jcontainer = $j('#portfolio-list');
$jcontainer.imagesLoaded( function() {
// initialize isotope
$jcontainer.isotope({
  filter: '*',
  itemSelector : '.post',
  layoutMode : 'masonry',
});
});

$j('#portfolio-filter a').click(function(){
    $j('#portfolio-filter .current').removeClass('current');
    $j('#portfolio-list .match').removeClass('match');
    $j(this).addClass('current');
    var selector = $j(this).attr('data-filter');
    $j('#portfolio-list article' ).each(function() {
       if ($j(this).attr('class').match(new RegExp(selector))) {
        $j(this).addClass('match');
    }
    }); 

    $jcontainer.isotope({
        filter: '.match',
     });
     return false;
});
```